# how to write "DATE" data type in spark-csv

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-csv, databricks

i have data similar to this.

```
no,full_name,Ocupation,DOB
1,Eugene Perry,Physical Therapy Assistant,11/22/1972
2,Scott Evans,Account Executive,8/25/1961
3,Harold Porter,Community Outreach Specialist,4/5/1986
4,Roger Turner,Account Coordinator,12/24/1989
5,Patrick Freeman,Geological Engineer,2/11/1990
6,Jonathan Hart,Safety Technician I,7/24/1963
7,Susan Jenkins,Nurse,4/17/1967
8,Jason Graham,Internal Auditor,10/18/1966
9,Mark Wells,VP Marketing,2/20/1990
```

My Code Similar to this:(Java)

```
 SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("Java Spark SQL Example")
                .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
                .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///C:/tmp/") 
                .getOrCreate();

       StructType Const = new StructType(new StructField[] {
            new StructField("no", DataTypes.IntegerType, true, Metadata.empty()),
            new StructField("full_name", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
            new StructField("Ocupation", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
            new StructField("DOB", DataTypes.DateType, true, Metadata.empty())
        });
                Dataset<Row> Tem  =  spark.read().format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
                        .schema(Const).option("header", "true").option("delimiter", ",").option("dateFormat", "MM/DD/YYYY")
                        .load("E:\\Datasets\\people.csv");

                Tem.show();
                Tem.printSchema();
                Tem.coalesce(1).write()
                    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
                    .option("header", "true").option("dateFormat", "MM/DD/YYYY")
                    .save("E:\\Datasets\\output");
```

Above code works fine without errors,but DATE datatype( "DOB" )column is not properly printed in flat file.

my Actual result is :

```
no,full_name,Ocupation,DOB
1,Eugene Perry,Physical Therapy Assistant,724
2,Scott Evans,Account Executive,-3287
3,Harold Porter,Community Outreach Specialist,5841
4,Roger Turner,Account Coordinator,6940
5,Patrick Freeman,Geological Engineer,7304
6,Jonathan Hart,Safety Technician I,-2559
```

even though i am using `.option("dateFormat", "MM/DD/YYYY")` .

see last column , "DATE" formatting isn't working in .csv file. 
i am not sure what i am missing.

Comment: Try `.option("dateFormat", "MM/dd/YYYY")`

Comment: i tried , its not working.you can check in my code

Comment: Tried with `dd` ?

Comment: dd is not similar to DD. @MRSrinivas might be right.

Comment: Tried both. results are -ive

Comment: seems none of the format has any impact on output.

Comment: @sriramkumar - which version of spark are you using?

Comment: i am using  spark-sql_2.10  -v 2.0.0(org.apache.spark) & spark-csv_2.10 -v 1.5.0(com.databricks)

Comment: Did you resolve this? I have the same problem: dateFormat option is not working.

Comment: @nicola this is problem with spark 2.0.0 .  this issue is resolved in its next version. (spark 2.0.1)

Comment: I actually have the problem with Spark 2.1.0. I will try to run it with 2.0.1 version anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is associated with the spark version 2.0.0.

Upgrading to spark 2.0.1 and using the built-in spark CSV format fixes the issue.

reference [link](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/392)

Comment: facing the same issue even though I am using Spark 2.4.5